# PHP: parse_url decodes characters

Tags: php, url

so the problem is strange, cause it's happening on some systems only.

If you have this line:

```
parse_url('/€?€#€')
```

On local system with PHP version 7.0.4 it gives me the following result:

```
array(3) {        
  ["path"]=>      
  string(4) "/▒_▒"
  ["query"]=>     
  string(3) "▒_▒" 
  ["fragment"]=>  
  string(3) "▒_▒" 
}
```

Something like that is experienced here:

https://www.functions-online.com/parse_url.html

Enter in the $url box:

```
/€?€#€
```

But here it's working just fine, although the PHP version is the same as on my machine:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/

Any idea why is that happening?

The expected parsed url result should be:

```
array(3) {
  ["path"]=>
  string(4) "/€"
  ["query"]=>
  string(3) "€"
  ["fragment"]=>
  string(3) "€"
}
```

EDIT:

File encoding is UTF-8, PHP internal encodings are also UTF-8, everything that can be set on the server is already UTF-8.

Comment: It's not the encoding ... everything is in UTF-8 and PHP Version is above 7, in which by default internal encodings are UTF=8...

Comment: So what is the table encoding?